# An object contains a collection of objects - each with an id and name, how do I separate them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

At the moment I have this object:

```
obj = [object{id: 1, name: test, parentID: 3}, object{id:1, name: another, parentID: 5}, object{id:2, name:something, parentID: 1}].
```

Ultimately I want an object structured in a different manner.
So that it is object, but if my identifier is 1, it has a collection of names (in this case test, and another). If it is 2, it only shows 'something'.

I can't work out how this should look, probably like so?
`obj = [[1,test], [1,another], [2,something]]` right?

So that if I call obj[1] I get a multiples back (test, another etc).

Can someone help? I've been fiddling with this for an hour now, I just don't understand.

I built the original object like this:

```
var obj = Array();
//loop here
  var obj = {
     id: id,
     name: name,
     parentID: parentID
  };
  obj.push(obj);
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this? This got me my object within objects thing, but really I want id's and names within id's and names. My ultimate goal is to iterate through this. So that I only get out the names of anything of a like ID, that way I can use this to populate an array or count

Thus:

```
if(obj[id] == 1){
  //put the name in the new array
}
```

is my ultimate goal. But I've gotten a bit lost with the initial object creation so now it is a big mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var obj = [{id: 1, name: "Foo"}, {id: 2, name: "Fee"}, {id: 3, name: "Fii"}];
var result = [], item, i = 0;
while(item = obj[i++]){
    for(key in item){
        if(key === "id") continue; //remove this line if you want to keep the ID also in the array
        !result[i] && (result[i] = []);
        result[i].push(item[key]);
    }
}
console.log(result[1]); // --> ["Foo"]
```

Comment: Brilliant, a follow up question. if I wanted to get the id of each result[i], or the name, is there a way to do this with the new result of: obj = [[1,test], [1,another], [2,something]], or is this not possible with the absence of keyname? For example - if I wanted to iterate through and send only  results where item id is 1 to a new array

Comment: Updated. Try:  console.log(result[1])

Comment: You made a good point, it is lighter. EDIT - never mind I worked out my final query, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is walk the array of objects one time. Each time through, you want to check your new object to see if that id exists yet. If it does, add the name. If not, make a new entry for that id and add an array with one entry. Note, this doesn't handle duplicate names (it just adds it again).

```
var array = [{id:1, name:"test"}, 
             {id:1, name:"another"},
             {id:2, name:"something"}];

var result = {};
array.forEach(function(item) {
  if (result[item.id]) {
    result[item.id].push(item.name);
  }
  else {
    result[item.id] = [item.name];
  }
});

console.log(result[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
var sourceObject=[{id:0,name:'Tahir'},{id:0,name:'Ahmed'},{id:1,name:'David'},{id:1,name:'G'},{id:2,name:'TA'},{id:3,name:'DG'}];
function getNames(id){
    var names=[],length=sourceObject.length,i=0;
    for(i;i<length;i+=1){
        if(sourceObject[i].id===id){
            names[names.length]=sourceObject[i].name;
        }
    }
    return names;
}
console.log(getNames(1));
```

Comment: @DavidG Keep in mind that in my example does the same, gets the array as a result[1], it is even lighter